# filtering Tables In Javascript via modal Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

This is the first JS script i've written on my own so bear with me. i have a table with info fed from my db, instead of using a search input filter i have a modal box with checkboxes allowing users to specify the data they want to see in the table by the location column

The script i'm writing grabs the main table, loops through the rows and if the text in the column does not match the location display nothing.

```
function filterTable(choice){
  let i,  data,cell,tr, txtValue,;

   //options = document.getElementsByClassName("options")

   data = document.getElementById("mainTable")
   tr = data.getElementsByTagName("tr");

   for (i = 0; i < tr.length ; i++) {
       cell = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];


           if (cell) {
                txtValue = cell.textContent || cell.innerText;
                if(txtValue !== choice)
                tr[i].style.display = " "
               
           }else {
               tr[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
```

the function is called upon clicking one of the checkboxes, the specific locations are passed in as the param

```
<div id="Location" class="tabcontent">
                <p class="options">Ohio <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterTable( 'Ohio')"/> </p>
                <p class="options">New York <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterTable( 'New York')" /></p>
                <p class="options">Connecticut <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterTable( 'Connecticut')"/></p>
                <p class="options">Maryland <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterTable( 'Maryland')"/></p>
                <p class="options">Delaware <input type="checkbox" onclick="filterTable( 'Delaware')"/></p>
              </div>
Also the main td im trying to target is the last one that holds the locations shown here indexed at 6

         <tr class="header">
               <th > Rank </th>

               <th > Auction House </th>

               <th onclick="sortTable(2)" class="pointer" >APR</th>

               <th onclick="sortTable(3)" class="pointer"  > Weekly Change</th>

               <th onclick="sortTable(4)" class="pointer" >Fee's</th>
                <th >Shipping</th>
                <th >Location</th>
            </tr>



           <tr>
              <td >{{x[0]}}</td>
              <td><a >{{x[1]}} </a> </td>
        <td id="apr"> {{x[2]}}&#37;</td>
        <td id="wkly"> {{x[3]}}&#37;</td>
                <td id="fee"> {{x[4]}}&#37;</td>
                <td id="ship"> {{x[5]}}</td>
                <td id="loc"> {{x[6]}}</td>

            </tr>
```

With the current script ,after clicking on any of the checkboxes the header row disappears and the rest of the rows are shown.

So i tried to skip the header row in the for loop

```
for (i = 1; (i < tr.length -1 ); i++)
```

This made sure the header row stayed intact but affected none of the rows with the actual data.

In short i'm trying to hide all rows that have text elements in the 6th column that don't match the one chosen with the checkbox. Thanks

Comment: your method `filterTable` has `n` as the first param and `choice` as the second one. Your onclicks are only passing 1 param to the method, so that would be `n` however inside the method you are only using the param `choice` which is always empty since you're not passing 2 params

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake, n before was representing the index of the td but i ended up changing that, the code im working with now has the n removed

Comment: I don't know if this is your solution, but looking at your original post i see this check: `txtValue = cell.textContent || cell.innerText;` keep in mind that when reading from the DOM its very likely you end up with white space inserted by the browser before or after your string. Also keep in mind that uppercase / lowercase matters. Your check should become `txtValue = (cell.textContent || cell.innerText).trim().toLowerCase(); if(txtValue !== choice.toLowerCase()) { /* rest of your code here */ }`

Comment: Thank you Georgi! I found your reply very helpful. I also noted that my if txtValue statement lacked trailing curly braces. So once i made those changes everything was working. Thanks again!